# regexp_replace: insert a space in a string if not already present

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have an Oracle table that contains names of towns. Some names start with st. (saint) followed by a space, e.g. `st. ulrich`, some without as `st.paul`.
I would like to add the space after the dot where it is missing. 
I would also like to strip multiple spaces.

Is this possible with `regexp_replace` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using the `REGEXP_REPLACE` function:

```
-- Match the string "st." followed by zero or more spaces and a word character,
-- replace it with "st." followed by exactly one space and the captured character
select city,
       regexp_replace(city, 'st\.\s*(\w)', 'st. \1' ) as city_formatted
  from t
 order by city;
```

Output:

```
CITY               CITY_FORMATTED      
------------------ --------------------
st.   triple space st. triple space    
st.  double space  st. double space    
st. ulrich         st. ulrich          
st.paul            st. paul
```