# Add spaces before Capital Letters in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to insert a space before the capital letters in oracle.   I thought it would be easy using a regexp_replace, but I can't seem to get a proper back reference to the character I am replacing.

```
select trim(regexp_replace ('FreddyFox', '[A-Z]', ' \1' )) from dual;

Result: '\1reddy \1ox'
```

I have tried multiple variants of a back reference but I can't seem to find something that satisfies Oracle.

I did look at multiple SO answers but I could not figure out what is wrong.
e.g. [regexp_replace: insert a space in a string if not already present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223560/regexp-replace-insert-a-space-in-a-string-if-not-already-present)

Comment: probably `regexp_replace ('FreddyFox', '([A-Z])', ' \1' ))`

Comment: @Lashane , Bingo. Make it an answer and I will give it to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
TRIM(regexp_replace ('FreddyFox', '([A-Z])', ' \1' ))
```

Comment: And in case you also want to reduce multiple space characters to one: `TRIM(regexp_replace ('FreddyFox  <multiple spaces here>   Fainted', '\s*([A-Z])', ' \1' ))`.  Comment section seems to automatically strip multiple spaces.  How ironic.

Answer (score 0):

TRIM enables you to trim leading or trailing characters (or both) from a character string. If trim_character or trim_source is a character literal, then you must enclose it in single quotes. Default is both.

```
regexp_replace ('FreddyFox', '^([A-Z])', ' \1')
```